# Cannot query UI elements when in modal

Tags: xcode, xcuitest

Using Xcode 13.3.1 and XCUITest, no UI controls appear in the queries when they are on a modal. Only the elements in the view controller that the modal is over appear. Is this an Xcode version bug or a sad reality of attempting to seriously use XCUITest?

Comment: is it a system modal? If so you may need to access them via Springboard app, rather than your own

Comment: A modal in the sense when you call `present` within your own app. Not a system modal.

Comment: Thanks! Can you probably share some code? You can't see these elements in XCUIApplication().debugDescription too, right?

Comment: @laechoppe Are you able to query controls on a modal? I'm 100% certain I could not after many attempts.